# display values within stacked boxes of rowstacked histograms in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot (Version 4.4 patchlevel 2) to generate rowstacked histograms, very similar to the example called "Stacked histograms by percent" from the gnuplot demo site at http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/histograms.html

I want to display the values of each stacked box within it.

I.e. I want to display the actual numerical value (in percent and/or the absolute number) of each box.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

How many numbers do you want to enter.

If it is just a few then have you tried

```
set label "label" at 2,3
```

If there are many then you can write a script to decide where to put the numbers - something like here

[Plotting arrows with gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815326/plotting-arrows-with-gnuplot/4817169#4817169)

Don't know a way to do it by magic, although I am not very familiar with rowstacked histograms

Tom